# Map Retrofit Response in Custom Model Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

onSuccess() of retrofit

```
override fun onSuccess(call: Call<Any?>?, response: Response<Any?>, tag: Any?) {
        when (tag) {
            RequestCodes.API.LOGIN -> {
                val apiResponse = response.body() as? ModelAPIResponse

            val toast = Toast.makeText(
                MainApplication.applicationContext(),
                "Api Success=${apiResponse?.message}",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            )
            toast.show()}}}
```

Image of database body

[image]

Model For Api Response

```
@SerializedName("statusCode")
var statusCode: String? = null
@SerializedName("message")
var message: String? = null
```

Comment: Please provide full description of your code and what you want

Comment: I have Also added the image with debugger showing the on success function is working fine with response i just need to know how i can map the response in model class . in java all i had to do was cast the response as Required Model (as ModelAPiResponse in my Case) and response is mapped in my desired model. i don't know how i can achieve that same thing with kotlin in android

Comment: What you exactly want?

Comment: To Map api response in custom model

Answer (score 0):

try make the Json Response to Object class Like this

```
data class ApiResponse(
   @SerializedName("statusCode")
   var statusCode: String? = null
   @SerializedName("message")
   var message: String? = null
)
```

then on your retrofit API call

```
 @GET("your_endpoint")
    fun getCartListAsync(): Call<ApiResponse>
```

then on your success change the `Call<Any>` into `Call<ApiResponse>`

Comment: That's One way to Go For Sure i did Thought of That but I want to Map any response in api into data model . In answer you  mentioned i will get a specific data model in return. Suppose some time in future the data fields are changed from back-end then the specific data model used in Call<> method is useless. In Case of Any if the fields are changed from back-end even then i have response to map in other model

Comment: i think you can't do it like that, except you have Base Response model, Like parsing "meta":{} "data":{}, but for the data you must make a data class for the Json Data

Answer (score 0):

I have Found a Way to map the response the do the same thing in IOS which is writing a mapper

```
  val apiResponse = ModelAPIResponse(response.body() as LinkedTreeMap<String, String>)
```

then in data model

```
class ModelAPIResponse(data: LinkedTreeMap<String, String>) {
var statusCode: String? = null
var message: String? = null

init {
    this.message = data["message"]
    this.statusCode = data["statusCode"]
}}
```

Comment: If anyone can improve the answer then i will really appreciate it